# Usage of "to do with"

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

Can I use "to do with" in the same meaning as "about/concerning a particular subject" ?

For example:

> 1- All applications ***to do with this role***  go through my secretary first.
>
> 2- Most of the articles ***are to do with*** microbiota's role in the
>   colon cancer.
>
> 3- ***Was the dispute to do with*** safety regulations?

I made up these examples above.

Comment: All your examples are fine, but note that ***to do with*** is far more "casual / colloquial" than, say, ***concerning, regarding***. Note that in context #1 (but not #2 or #3, I think), it's preceded by implied but unstated ***which are***. In that context (and perhaps others), you could include either ***which are*** or ***having*** - *All applications **having** to do with this role go through my secretary first* would be a perfectly natural utterance, which some might prefer to the version as given above. Or more emphatically, *... having **anything** to do with this role*.

Comment: This sounds like usage that depends on what type of English you are dealing with. In US English we usually try to insert the verb "to have" into this idiom: "applications **having** to do with this role go through my secretary"; "Did it **have** to do with safety?" Your sentences sound (to me) like they *may* be fine in some other varieties of English.